# Multi-parametric regression in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, regression, curve-fitting

I have a curve which looks roughly / qualitative like the curves displayed in those 3 images.

The only thing I know is that the first part of the curve is hardware-specific supposed to be a linear curve and the second part is some sort of logarithmic part (might be a combination of two logarithmic curves), i.e. linlog camera. But I couldn't tell the mathematic structure of the equation, e.g. wether it looks like `a*log(b)+c` or `a*(log(c+b))^2` etc. Is there a way to best fit/find out a good regression for this type of curve and is there a certain way to do this specifically in MATLAB? :-) I've got the student version, i.e. all toolboxes etc.

Comment: A Neural Network will definitely work in your case without thinking about the structure of the mathematical structure of the function. A very simple one: One hidden layer and few nodes.

Comment: But how would then the mathamtical equation look like? Don't I have to start with a fixed parametric equation frist for that?

Comment: lol wtf, why voting down on this one? At least leave a comment when voting down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fminsearch` is a very general way to find best-fit parameters once you have decided on a parametric equation.  And the optimization toolbox has a range of more-sophisticated ways.

Comparing the merits of one parametric equation against another, however, is a deep topic. The main thing to be aware of is that you can *always* tweak the equation, adding another term or parameter or whatever, and get a better fit in terms of lower sum-squared-error or whatever other goodness-of-fit metric you decide is appropriate.  That doesn't mean it's a good thing to keep adding parameters: your solution might be becoming overly complex.  In the end the most reliable way to compare how well two different parametric models are doing is to cross-validate:  optimize the parameters on a subset of the data, and evaluate only on data that the optimization procedure has not yet seen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The main problem I'm currently still seeing is the how to decide on a parametric equation because I' not a mathematician and therefore don't really know which type of equation makes sense to start with :(

Comment: The equation should be motivated as far as possible by an understanding of the process that produces these data. So you probably need to find a physicist rather than a mathematician to discuss this with.

Comment: And if there's no idea of the process as the process is closed within a commercial product? I only know how it is supposed to look like qualitative from the manual (the 3 figures I posted above)...?

Comment: Well, then I don't know. Although this article title sounds about right: http://jstor.org/stable/2531321

Comment: I just wanted to implement a simple regression based on a parametric equation and looked on the help page of `fminsearch` -> How is this supposed to help me with a regression? From what I read this function calculates the minimum of a function which already exists as a function handle and NOT the parameters of a parametric equation to best fit to data

Comment: Finding "the parameters of a parametric equation to best fit to data" is exactly what `fminsearch` does although possibly the doc may be hard to read.  Define an "objective function" g which might be stated as "the sum squared error (or other error metric) of the fit to data x using equation e using parameters p". g, x and e are constant, p is varied during the search, to find, not just the minimum value of g, but also the value of parameters p that get you there. If this is still unclear I suggest looking for example code that uses fminsearch.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the "function finder" on my curve fitting web site zunzun.com and see what it comes up with - it is free.  If you have any trouble please email me directly and I'll do my best to help.

James Phillips
zunzun@zunzun.com